# AngularJS with ng-pattern in form does not send invalid field to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-pattern

I want to validate a text input in form, so the submit of the form could not be done until the input match a regular expression. But when I type a wrong field value and I clik submit the form is submitted but the input value is not sent to the server. I want the same behaviour as with HTML5 required Attribute. This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left">APN</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label"></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="apn" ng-model="Configure3gCtrl.configure3g.apn" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9-.]*$/" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats how angular works it will not set the value in ng-model unless its valid. you have to check validity of form in the submit function.

Comment: value not sent because when you pass the input with incorrect pattern the `ng-model` is `undefined`

Comment: With ng-required the submit button does not submit the form until the field is not empty. Could I achieve something similar for ng-pattern not coding it in the controller function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As i said in the comment* [value not sent because when you pass the input with incorrect pattern the `ng-model` is `undefined`].

But we can use the form validation here as sample if our `ng-model` are `invalid` the form will disabled.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "$filter", function($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.submit = function() {
    console.log($scope.object)
  }

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <form name="form">
    <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left">APN</label>
    <input type="text" name="apn" ng-model="object.apn" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9-.]*$/" required />
    <button ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">submit</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should not send the invalid value to server, So you should `disable\hide` your submit button, but if you really require sending the invalid value as well to server, then from **angularjs 1.3+** you have **`ng-model-options`** ([Read Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)) directive which can help you.

Simply mark your `text type` input as `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true }"`, It will persist the invalid values as well.

**See Demo:**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.submitt = function() {
    alert($scope.Configure3gCtrl.configure3g.apn);
  }
  $scope.Configure3gCtrl = {
    configure3g: {
      apn: ""
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="frm" ng-submit="submitt()" class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 label-on-left">APN</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label"></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="apn" 
        ng-model="Configure3gCtrl.configure3g.apn" 
        ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true }" 
        ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9-.]*$/" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

also, Test with removing `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: '$inherit' }"` from above code snippet then `ng-model` will be `undefined`, because it is invalid.